# How I can understand where is the conflict in libraries version?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Suddenly after I start using constraintLayout I got an error. I know that error is because of support library version. And I have already checked two main answers on stack. But anyway I got a question:

1. Is it ok that it add library with another version by itself?
2. How can I fix that? I need to put each library from left to right side and give it needed version?
3. Do I need to change versions of each file or I just need to add implementations on the right side?

I need to change versions here?
[image]

Or add it here
[image]

Thats the error
[image]

I know about - Go and ready about Gradle - I am already doing that:) Thank you for your time guys!

Comment: In build.gradle, just change the versions of the design and support libraries to the same version of either 27.0.2 or 26.1.0. All should have same version. Once you've done rebuild the project and it should be fine

Comment: @ShobhitPuri the same problem after I changed everything to 27.0.2